# subject-verb agreement When two singular words are joined by not only . . . but also

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> When neither… nor… or either… or… are used with two singular nouns, the verb can be singular or plural. A plural verb is more informal.[From Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/either_1?q=either)

I wonder if When not only . . . but also is used with two singular nouns, the verb can also be singular or plural.

Answer (score 1):

In 'not only ... but also' the verb agrees with the subject nearest to it.

Compare:

- Not only a jacket but also **gloves are** worn in cold days.
- Not only gloves but also **a jacket is** worn in cold days.

Comment: *Your dress sense is terrible! Either the jacket or the gloves **have** to go!* OR *Either the gloves or the jacket **has** to go!*

Comment: Your dress sense is terrible! Either the jacket or the cat have/has to go! But not only the jacket but the cat has (not have) to go?